# erase textfield value on touch up inside

Tags: ios

I have a password textfield with a default value "password". The field is marked as secure. I'm trying to erase the default value once the user touch up inside the textfield.

```
- (IBAction)PasswordTouchUpInside:(id)sender
{
  if (Password.text == @"Password")
  {
    Password.text = @"";
  }
}
```

Is the touch up inside the wrong event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compare strings using the method [`isEqualToString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) in the if condition:

```
if ([Password.text isEqualToString:@"Password"]) {
    Password.text = @"";
}
```

Or, you can simply use the [`placeHolder`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006888-CH3-SW14) property so that the `UITextField` does this behaviour automatically without you having to write `PasswordTouchUpInside`.

Comment: is there a table explaining all the events behaviour anywhere?

Comment: @lolol - The apple [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events) is a good place to find such information.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want Touch Down, not up.